# How to make a new observation in Stata that has the average of all observations above it for all variables, but also ignore set observations?

Tags: stata

I did `insobs 1`  to add a new observation. But how do I make the average come for each variable in this observation? And how do I tell Stata to ignore certain observations (rows).

Comment: Storing an average as an extra observation is just going to make Stata life more complicated. What you want to do is more appropriate to working in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Unfourtunately I have to do this in Stata. Do you have any idea as to how to use this code: ```qui foreach v in `r(varlist)' {
su `v', meanonly
replace `v' = r(mean) in L
}``` but exclude specific observations?

Comment: Is this your code or someone else's? It's a way of operating that can only cause difficulties. (I didn't downvote this, but whoever wrote that code deserves a downvote, or something equivalent.)

Comment: More specifically, I've edited the spelling to Stata in two of your questions. That's a small thing you owe Stata users here who read your questions: please spell the name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `r(varlist)` is populated appropriately and the last observation is set up to receive averages, then everything depends on earlier code.

If the last observation is initialised to contain missing values, there is no problem.

Otherwise you must exclude the last observation from the calculation of the average.

```
local last = _N - 1 
foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    su `v' in 1/`last', meanonly 
    replace `v' = r(mean) in L 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to exclude certain observations? Let's say observation 3, 62, and 299