# How do I use the follow code in Stata and tell it to ignore certain observations when calculating the average?

Tags: stata

Previous Thread: [How to make a new observation in Stata that has the average of all observations above it for all variables, but also ignore set observations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179837/how-to-make-a-new-observation-in-stata-that-has-the-average-of-all-observations?noredirect=1#comment111724030_63179837)

The code is

```
local last = _N - 1 
foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    su `v' in 1/`last', meanonly 
    replace `v' = r(mean) in L 
}
```

How do I tell Stata to ignore rows 3, 62, and 99 when calculating the average?

Comment: You should cross-refer to your previous thread. See `help if` and `help in` for guidance. Assuming that there is a good reason for excluding particular observations  it is better to use a rule which makes that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow why you exclude the last row and why you use the `replace`. However, to exclude individual rows you could use an `if` statement, `inlist()` and `_n`.

Example:
`if !inlist(_n, 1)` would exclude first row.

In your case the code should be as follows (excludes rows 3, 62, 99 and the last one (`_N`)):

```
local last = _N - 1 
foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    su `v' if !inlist(_n, 3, 62, 99, _N), meanonly 
    replace `v' = r(mean) in L 
}
```

Comment: The OP's previous thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179837/how-to-make-a-new-observation-in-stata-that-has-the-average-of-all-observations explained why the last observation was being excluded: it is being used to store the mean. I advised vigorously against this practice in comments in that thread.

Comment: Helpful answer (+1), but I edited out a  passing but incorrect use of the word "macro".

Comment: Thank you for that. I still struggle with the correct terminology when it comes to stata.